# jQuery get select option value empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

```html
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="">All Category</option>
    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
    <option value="3">Category 3</option>
</select>
```

**How to choose the category with value=""**

**Conditions for a correct:**

```js
if($('#category option:selected')){
    var category_url = "&category="+$('#category').val();    
    <!-- True -->
}
```

**Condition 2 wrong:**

```js
if($('#category option[value=""]')){
    var category_url = "";                              
    <!-- Error  -->
}
```

Comment: Add what you are trying to achieve, so we can point you in the right direction.  For instance, your condition 2 will always return "true", since there will always exist a value="", even if that value is not selected.

Comment: This used to work in older versions of jquery (1.7.2) if you used ```$("option[value=]")```, but now it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!$("#category").val())
     //selected valule is ""
```

Comment: thank you so much. I did succeed with code: `var category_url = ''; if($('#category').val() != ''){ category_url = "&category="+$('#category').val(); }`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you looking to do something like this?

```
if($('#category option:selected')){
     var selValue = $('#category').val();
     var category_url;

     if(selValue)
         category_url = "&category="+$('#category').val();    <!-- True -->
     else
         <!-- error -->
}
```

Comment: `if($('#category option:selected')){` will *always* return `true`.  You need to check `length`.

Comment: thank you so much. I did succeed with code: `var category_url = ''; if($('#category').val() != ''){ category_url = "&category="+$('#category').val(); }`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but you could do:

```
$('#category').find('option:empty')
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, if you tell the browser to select nothing, it does the jox :

```
$("#category option").attr("selected", false); //Unselect each option
```

By default the browser Will select will show the first option, whatever is the option's value.

Hope this will helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For RadioButtons Group

```
 $("input[type='radio'][value='']").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is too old. But it can be useful for other people.

`$( <selector> ).find('option[value="<required-value>"]').attr('selected','selected')`